# Keyboard USB transform

Tags: usb, usb-device, output, input, keyboard

I want to press a key on my keyboard, for example "a" and a device should take the scan code of the button I pressed and transform it to something else: e.g. "b" or the scan code of b. What device can do such things? I need to be able to program it myself.
To clarify: I want to connect the device between the keyboard and the computer. I do not need a software inside the computer. I need it before the data arrives the computer.

I've already searched for keyboard encoders/emulators, but since I have already keyboard input, they can't help me.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. A microcontroller with two USB ports and a pile of software is how it would almost certainly be done in mass production. You can probably find microcontroller demo' boards with the required interfaces to develop on or use but you'll have to search for that yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a keyboard adapter or keylogger or man in the middle attack.

A microcontroller or SOC that can do usb peripheral as a usb hid keyboard, and that can either do PS/2 reading or USB host for a usb hid keyboard. The PS/2 reading is much easier. Some modern usb keyboards still work with a USB to PS/2 physical adapter.

A RPi can do it as it has usb host and usb OTG capability. Many microcontrollers can do it. Even some without native usb like V-Usb on a attiny. The devil is in the detail and timing. And coding. You may want to use multiple microcontrollers to break up the project, one for reading the keyboard and one for emulating a keyboard. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i belive that what your looking for is a BadUsb or some variation of it, thn just customize the code a little to fit your needs.