# Looking for advice on building a USB inline device to remap CapsLock key on USB keyboard

Tags: usb

I want to build a small inline USB device that changes the CapsLock key to be a Ctrl key. I want to do this because I rarely use the CapsLock key. Unfortunately, I don't have admin on the machine, so I can't use the regular approach (ie: registry change, or PowerToys).

So I need a microcontroller with USB-A and USB-B (host and device?) that can read USB codes from the keyboard and then send them to the computer.

What works to do this?

Comment: [Related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/560386/238590) recently asked.

Comment: You should be able to remap the caps lock key using your OS. If not, get a better OS. I've done this on every keyboard I use, including my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a product that has both: a USB device interface and a USB host interface.

1. USB Device interface (keyboard emulation)
   The PC (host) wants to see a keyboard (device) attached.
2. USB Host interface (PC mimic)
   The keyboard (device) wants to talk to a PC (host)

---

The problems are the USB software stacks

You need to have the source code of a HID USB device software stack to emulate a keyboard.

You need to have the source code of a USB host software stack in order to talk to the keyboard.

Afterwards, you need to slightly modify the HID device software to fit your needs.

---

I think that Microchip and NXP have the right microcontroller and the software stacks.

Their software stacks are open source but you have to use them in their microcontrollers.

Answer (score 2):

All the Teeny controllers have great Keyboard emulation support (Joystick,mouse,serial,flight control as well).  Many DIY keyboard builds use them.
You could use a Teensy LC and a USB Host Shield v2.0..
Look at the Teensy 4.1.  It has the pins broken out for USB host and mounts easily as a keyboard.  It will only use 1% of the Teensy processing power but that is progress.
https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy40.html

Comment: That certainly looks like the right device. Thanks.